# Why do we still have `doc_types` in ElasticSearch Index?

Tags: elasticsearch

One of the "Breaking changes" in Elasticsearch 6.0 was the removal of multiple mapping types within an index.
The [release notice](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/breaking-changes-6.0.html) states that

> The ability to have multiple mapping types per index has been removed in 6.0. New indices will be restricted to a single type.

The reason for this removal is given [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html#_why_are_mapping_types_being_removed)

> In an Elasticsearch index, fields that have the same name in different mapping types are backed by the same Lucene field internally.
>
> This can lead to frustration when, for example, you want deleted to be a date field in one type and a boolean field in another type in the same index.
>
> On top of that, storing different entities that have few or no fields in common in the same index leads to sparse data and interferes with Lucene’s ability to compress documents efficiently.

Their solution to have different Mappings it to `have an index per document type.`

**My question is why do we need `doc_types` anymore? Isn't it just a nested index now?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch 6 uses it for backward compatibility with 5.x.  Elasticsearch 7 deprecates it, as is a standard practice for wanting to remove something in a future update.

Elasticsearch major versions support indices created by the previous major version, otherwise everyone would lose their data upon updating.  It will be removed completely in 8.0.0.

Comment: Just to confirm, I found it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html#_why_are_mapping_types_being_removed) that it will be completely removed in 8.0.0.